# Build error: Interop code cannot be compiled by .Net Native

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-native

After I've had lots and lots of issues with UWP which could not be reproduced by others I wanted to try whether .Net Native compilation (haven't tried it yet) does fix issues for me. But I can't even compile my app with that.

```
1>"C:\Project\\RIVI\RIVI\RIVI.csproj" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
1>(BuildNativePackage target) ->
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0028: Found native library 'C:\Project\\RIVI\RIVI\obj\x64\Debug\ilc\in\sharpdx_direct3d11_1_effects_x86.dll' with unexpected CPU architecture 'x86', while the current build target architecture is set to 'amd64'. Your application may fail to launch. Please make sure to build your application with the matching CPU architecture.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegCloseKey' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegCloseKey(System.IntPtr)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegQueryValueExW' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegQueryValueEx(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle, System.String, System.Int32[], System.Int32, System.Byte[], System.Int32)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegEnumKeyExW' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegEnumKeyEx(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle, System.Int32, System.Char*, System.Int32, System.Int32[], System.Text.StringBuilder, System.Int32[], System.Int64[])'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegQueryValueExW' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegQueryValueEx(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle, System.String, System.Int32[], System.Int32, System.Int64, System.Int32)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegQueryValueExW' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegQueryValueEx(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle, System.String, System.Int32[], System.Int32, System.Int32, System.Int32)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegQueryValueExW' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegQueryValueEx(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle, System.String, System.Int32[], System.Int32, System.Char[], System.Int32)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegOpenKeyExW' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegOpenKeyEx(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle, System.String, System.Int32, System.Int32, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll!RegQueryInfoKeyW' for method 'System.Int32 Interop.mincore.RegQueryInfoKey(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle, System.Text.StringBuilder, System.Int32[], System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.Int32[], System.Int32[], System.Int32, System.Int32[], System.Int32[], System.Int32[], System.Int32[])'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
1>
1>
1>"C:\Project\\RIVI\RIVI\RIVI.csproj" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
1>(BuildNativePackage target) ->
1>  C:\Users\et49725\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(731,5): error : Internal compiler error: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to compile interop source code. See the build log for error details.)
1>
1>    38 Warning(s)
1>    1 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:01:23.91
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It always says that *compilation of interop source code failed*. The mentioned interop methods exist nowhere in my code. I don't even think that any referenced package does use them. And so I don't even know how to fix that.

How can I solve that? Eventually I got to use .Net Native compilation.

Comment: When you want to paste errors, do as I just edited. It's easier to read

Comment: It seems like you are using `sharpdx_direct3d11_1_effects_x86.dll`. This sounds like 1st problem *(according to warning you try to compile for `amd64`)*. 2nd: library `api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll` for accessing registry. Sorry I'm not a expert in UWP API, but from the message it seems, like registry API is not an allowed API in UWP. Unfortunately these are only warnings. The real error is a **Internal compiler error**. When it is not caused by the warnings, then it is probably a unspecified error. Reinstall of compiler might help, but also might not help...

Comment: I already reinstalled Visual Studio completely. And both versions of the effects library are referenced, so this shouldn't be the issue. Yes, likely it's unsupported but I don't even use the registry. I also don't know of any referenced third-party assembly which would use it. Honestly, I'm fed up with UWP. It's so incredibly unreliable as of my experience so far... yet I have no other option, sadly. @CamiloTerevinto I will, sorry. Forgot that code doesn't break lines.

Comment: Does this happens if you try with a new, empty project? If not, then I'd try to de-reference the libraries that Julo mentions

Comment: .NETNative is able to diagnose problems you'd normally discover with the WACK tool.  The first error is a plain one, you'll have to build the x86 version of the project so you can use a 32-bit native dll.  Having a dependency on the RegXxx winapi functions is a showstopper, you can't submit your app to the Store as a UWP package with such a dependency.  It doesn't have anything to do with "reliability", UWP is basically a different operating system that is as different as, say, MacOS from iOS.  Meant to target mobile devices, that small battery does require a different kind of programming.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop

Comment: I removed the effects library for x86 completely. Warning gone, error persists. The app probably won't be distributed to the store anyway since it's customer-only. But still, it does not compile successfully so I could try. It does work in other projects and in empty ones. But besides that issue UWP does behave completely different on my machine than on others obviously. I've been struggling to get some of the DevExpress controls to work and not even their own test projects worked at my PC whereas they did at theirs. After reinstalling VS I still got errors but different ones...

Comment: "After reinstalling VS I still got errors but different ones", did you mean the above exceptions have resolved and you have new issue? Could you please update your question?

Comment: No I do get these afterwards. But I had different outcomes on three different UWP projects (on made from the DevExpress support, one test myself and my actual project) after re-installing. Not working but I had different exceptions during runtime. But that's a different story. Now it's about the impossible native build.